# What tools can I use to profile a .Net application in Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, profiler

Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition doesn't contain the profiler.  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

What free alternatives are there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any Good Free .NET Profiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MS has provided a [stand alone tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23205) that you can use

Comment: Thanks, this does the job, although it wasn't very obvious how to get going with it.  I'm using the VSPerfASPNetCmd.exe that comes with this installer and it's generated stats for me against a deployed instance of the website.

Comment: I also needed to do the following for anyone reading this late: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2010/07/23/tip-fixing-vsperfaspnetcmd-metabase-errors.aspx

Answer (score 1):

EQATEC Profile is the only free one that I'm aware of, but I've never used it. http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/

I've personally had great success with JetBrains' dotTrace profiler in the past. http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

RedGate also has their ANTS Performance Profiler product. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Neither of these are free, although usually the trial period is enough to diagnose a few problems to work on for awhile. :)

Comment: -1 - OP specifically asks for free, and you provide non-free options.

Comment: Free alternative added. Also I do point out that the pay ones have free trials which I will stand by as a loop hole. :P

Comment: That's the main reason why EQATEC Profiler doesn't have a trial license, but a free version with restricted functionality.

Answer (score 1):

AQtime: http://smartbear.com/products/free-tools/aqtime-standard/

Another good alternative is the built in profiler that comes with SharpDevelop: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/